# System.AccessViolationException in any OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4.GL Methods

Tags: c#, access-violation, opentk

I'm currently learning OpenTK(v 3.1). But there is a problem.
System.AccessViolationException is always thrown when I call GL.~~~() functions.

```cs
using System;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4;

namespace OpenTKTut
{
    internal class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GL.GetString(StringName.Version)); // where the error is thrown
            using (MainWindow mw = new MainWindow())
            {
                mw.VSync = OpenTK.VSyncMode.Off;
                mw.Run(144, 144);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error Message (Korean translated to English)

```
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   location: OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4.GL.GetString(StringName name) file I:\work\github\opentk\src\OpenTK\Graphics\OpenGL4\GL4.cs:line 28182
   location: OpenTKTut.Program.Main(String[] args) file D:\.vsworkplace\OpenTKTut\OpenTKTut\Program.cs:line 12
```

I was surprised that the file "I:\work\github\opentk\src\OpenTK\Graphics\OpenGL4\GL4.cs" isn't in my computer or storage...

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can only call GL functions after an OpenGL context is created, which is done by opening a window.

You'll want to move the `GL.GetString` into the `using` block.